# value of a public company with no profits

Tags: stocks

TAL Education Group has 5.94B in cash and 4.15B in debt, according to [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TAL/key-statistics?p=TAL).

There is news out that the company, along with other companies that provide school-age tutoring in China, will be forced by the government to become non-profit. They will also be banned from raising capital.

As an investor, I'm interested in how to value the company. Its stock price  dropped 60% today.

Assuming it will still be a publicly traded company, would the market cap be roughly cash minus debt, or are there other factors that might significantly influence the market cap?

Answer (score 1):

If the company is organized as a non-profit, then the main benefits of owning many companies: dividends, are non existent. Any profits generated by the business would then me funneled back into the business, they wouldn't be able to be distributed to stock owners.

If the company was going to convert from a for profit to a non-profit company, then there will be a fundamental change to the corporation. How this would be engineered would be of great interest to the current shareholders. What would happen to the value they hold via the shares? That uncertainty could cause the stock price to drop like a stone. It would be very tough to find people to buy your shares.

> Assuming it will still be a publicly traded company, would the market
> cap be roughly cash minus debt, or are there other factors that might
> significantly influence the market cap?

Market cap is the number of shares times the price of a share.

The ability for a non-profit to issue shares would depend on the laws of the country.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, for-profit colleges that came under government pressure converted to non-profit colleges with a for-profit 'services' provider. Theoretically, the non-profit Grand Canyon University could sever ties with its services provider, Grand Canyon Education Inc. (NASDAQ: LOPE). But LOPE shareholders are betting that the two entities will continue their ties indefinitely.